# How to only allow access if all matches are true in firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In firestore we can set our own security rules. I have added 2 security rules where i gave all crud operations access in 1st rule and deny delete access to all documents of a specific collection in 2nd rule. But due to the true condition of 1st rule, 2nd rule's condition is neglected as it is already mentioned in the document that for any true condition access is granted.

Is there any way that i can make in AND instead of OR.

Below are my rules for reference:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  function isAuthenticated(){
    return request.auth.uid != null;
  }
  match /{collection}/{document = **}{
    allow get, update, delete, create: if isAuthenticated()
  }     
    match /records/{record} {
        allow delete: if false
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No all rules are OR so as soon it resolves to true on the the query, update etc it 
will be processed.

It wouldn't be good practice to allow full crud to any user as they can just purge your database. Even if they are a good actor it can still accidentally happen with the wrong code.

Comment: Yeah i understand, Now i reversed the process and give full access to a specific set of user(say SuperUserGroup) and give specific access depends upon their conditon.

Comment: Still wouldn't give full access even to a super user to put whatever they want in your documents. You want to validate the data going in conforms to your data structure etc. But your call.